# Cant connect express app

Tags: node.js, express

Locally I can connect to my express app on port 9000. If I start it on remote server I am unsuccessful to reach app, but I see in console logs that it successfully starts.

I see next output for netstat command after `$my-express-app pm2 start bin/www`

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      52407/www       
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      43298/server.js 
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      52407/www
```

And next if I start as  `$my-express-app pm2 start app.js`

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      43298/server.js 
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      53096/app.js
```

My setup configuration is next

```
    ...................
    app.set('port', 9000)
    ...................
    app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

Have I missed something?

Express version is 4.x

**Update**

I also tried to bind app to listen any ip  `app.listen(app.get('port'),'0.0.0.0')`

I have add 2 input/output rules (udp rule was exist before)

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9000
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

`ufw status` tells me it inactive.

Have no sucess. Environment ubuntu 14.04

**Update**

I was able to run app on port 8000, where other js app is running normally. I cant find any settings related to this port. 9000 still not works. Below is nmap scan for 9000 port

```
nmap -p 9000 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-04 08:52 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000070s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
9000/tcp open  cslistener

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds

nmap -p 9000 myip

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-04 08:52 UTC
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.05 seconds
```

**RESOLVE**

I need to setup endpoint to port 9000 on azure portal. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your remote server firewall and add the port 9000 to be opened for traffic.

Answer (score 1):

What operating system are you using, and who is hosting this server for you? For example, I know that if you rent an Ubuntu server on DigitalOcean, most ports (including 9000) will be blocked by default by the firewall, ufw. If you're running on a new-ish version of Ubuntu, you can check your current firewall rules with `ufw status`. You may have to modify your firewall rules with `ufw allow 9000`.